# Is there an app for at least chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

I use Stack Exchange almost exclusively from my (Android) phone, where chat is basically unusable. A conversation on one of my questions got moved to chat. Is there an app or any other way to participate besides the main web UI?

Comment: There used to be... https://stackapps.com/q/4659/32479 .. You could nose about on StackApps to see if there is a current version.  If an app exists, that is where you'll find it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the chat UI is not very mobile friendly. But as far as I know, there is no longer an official stackexchange app. The old app didn't support chat anyway IIRC.

Perhaps there is a third party solution.